# How to scroll ListView with in another scroll view

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, scrollview

I have a problem;
I have a layout with scroll view over three list view A,B,C.
I want scroll hole layout as well as scroll each list view.

**Problem**:
List view are not scroll when layout is scroll if I remove scroll layout then list is scroll but layout is not scroll.

What is a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

We cant scroll listview within scrollview, because listview itself contains scroll option.

Check this link:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6552

By that listview bug can do that list in scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method and enjoy!

```
    private void setListViewScrollable(final ListView list) {
    list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                list.scrollBy(0, 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                list.scrollBy(0, -1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

listViewTouchAction is a global integer value.
If you can replace the line

```
list.scrollBy(0, 1);
```

with something else please share it with us.

Comment: how can i use it.Kindly give me some example because i have use it & not nothing doing for me

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want the view and how you want the scrolling to be.

If you want all of them scrollable, then you should apply a fixed height on the list views. It will sometimes confuse which will scroll first.

Or you can populate the whole list with no scroll inside a scroll view, which will create a long list with all items from all of the lists.